# Fragstats moving window analysis in R

Tags: r, fragstats

Does anyone know if it's possible to run a moving window analysis on either a raster, vector, matrix or data frame of spatial data to calculate Fragstats class statistics?

Comment: Take a look at the spatialEco package, there is functionality for landscape metrics using a moving window, on points with a specified radius and for polygons.